# How to Call Controller method from jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax call:

```
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCoverage", "Coverage")',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {},
        success: function (result, status, xhr) {
            alert("Result: " + status + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
        }
    });
})
```

...and the following controller method:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateCoverage()
    //public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateCoverage(string searchTerm = null)
    {
    }
```

...and my controller is

```
 public class CoverageController : BaseController
```

...

I get the error result. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: the url is simply /Coverage/UpdateCoverage. How is the rest determined, in this case localhost:50891/ ? Does the ajax call have to go in the View (cshtml)?

Comment: what error result do you get?

Comment: What error are you getting ? Check the browser devtools network tab and see the response for that call

Comment: 404 Not found error,

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var url='@(Url.Action("UpdateCoverage", "Coverage"))';
 $.get(url, function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.